# How do I target specific html elements to edit in CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4

I have a Validations Form in Ionic 4 that I am trying to edit with CSS. When I edit the form with CSS, it only seems to target elements of the form, after the form group has been clicked on.

Below I have attached the form in its before click state and after click state. I can't seem to target the forms elements state before it has been clicked on.

before click
[image: Before Click]

after click
[image: After Click]

Form.html

```
<ion-content  padding class="form-content">
    <form class="form" \[formGroup\]="validations_form" (ngSubmit)="tryLogin(validations_form.value)">

      <ion-item class="item item-trns text-center">
        <ion-label position="floating" >Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.email">
          <div class="error-message" *ngIf="validations_form.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('email').dirty || validations_form.get('email').touched)">
            {{ validation.message }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating" >Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password">
          <div class="error-message" *ngIf="validations_form.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('password').dirty || validations_form.get('password').touched)">
            {{ validation.message }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ion-button class="submit-btn" expand="block" type="submit" \[disabled\]="!validations_form.valid">Log In</ion-button>
      <label class="error-message">{{errorMessage}}</label>
    </form>
```

Form.css

```
form {
   margin-top: 99%;
}

.item.item-trns {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it might be the browser itself doing some form styling. There are issues around it injecting its own styles when it thinks it can autocomplete it for you. Try visiting it with an incognito browser and see if you still get these styles.

Comment: Also, when in doubt, throwing an `!important;` on the end of your style rules can help :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried including the element prior to adding more specificity?

```
ion-item .item-trns {
color: orange;
}
```

at first glance I cannot see why this would not work, possibly there is another rule elsewhere in the code that could be causing the issue -

You might be able to get around this by adding an id to the element?

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your can follow their docs - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties

```
ion-item {
  --color: orange;
}
```